# Grayed Out Ubuntu Distribution Updates

Tags: ubuntu, updates, screenshot

As shown in the screen-shot below, there are two updates under distribution updates that have been there for a couple of months now. These updates are not click-able and I see no way to get rid of them. So two part question, why did they get like this and how do I get rid of them?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grayed out packages mean that Update Manager is not able to install them due to an issue.

The issues are typically to do with resolving dependencies and conflicts. 
Try manually installing them through the Synaptic Package Manager or apt-get. That should throw up the error that causes Update Manager to not install these packages.

> $sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad

A typical scenario in which this could happen is if you have included in your sources a PPA that is pushing this package, but not some packages that this depends on.

Comment: ran that command from the command line and it just asked me if it could remove old packages to install the new ones. Thanks.